# "putObject" in AmazonS3 object does not use http (as configured), sticks to https instead

Tags: java, http, amazon-s3, https, aws-sdk

I have a *Test class where I'm making some calls to the amazon cloud, using the Java AWS SDK. For debugging reasons, I need to make those calls via ***http***, and not *https*.
I set it up in the @Before method, something like:

```
clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
this.amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()....withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)....build();
```

And later, in my test method, I have a few calls to the amazonS3 object:

```
PutObjectResult putObject = amazonS3.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, path, new ByteArrayInputStream(content), null);
...
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, path);
...
amazonS3.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, path);
```

I'm using wireshark to monitor the calls and the packets, and for some reason, **ALL** the calls are done using http, **except** the one using *putObject*. **That one stays on *https***.

It's not a timing issue/bug, I simply duplicated the calls, executed everything twice, still only the putObject sticks to https...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

==== LATER EDIT:
Here's a screenshot from debugging the *com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute* method, which gets called when I call *amazonS3.putObject(*... . There is http visible.
[image]

Comment: Does the path contains http:// or https://?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...
In the java code, there's no place where I set the path, the AWS SDK does that.
In WireShark, I intercept TLS calls corresponding to the putObject call.
Again, all the three calls in the code sample have exactly the same conditions...